# JavaScript content update

Tags: javascript, text

I'm trying to change the content from a `<div>` block **generated dynamicaly** using JavaScript. The change should be done on page load.

The block:

```
<div id="textbox_jbeeb_8" style="position: absolute; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; border-top-color: currentColor; border-left-color: currentColor; border-right-color: currentColor; border-bottom-color: currentColor; border-top-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-top-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; font-style: inherit; font-variant: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; outline-color: currentColor; outline-width: 0px; outline-style: none; background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: repeat; background-image: none; background-position: 0% 0%; background-size: auto; background-origin: padding-box; background-clip: border-box; background-color: transparent; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: inherit; transform-origin: 0px 0px; left: 0px; top: 31.25px; height: 8.75px; width: 50px; font-size: 8.75px; text-decoration: none; size: 8.75; white-space: nowrap; font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;, &quot;_sans&quot;; text-align: center; font-weight: 700; color: rgb(48, 48, 48); line-height: 1em; z-index: 1;">My text</div>
```

I tried to change content by adding

```
<script>
document.getElementById("textbox_jbeeb_8").innerHTML = "Updated text";
</script>
```

but there is no change. How else could I change the text?

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/xQ5qH/. Are you sure you're executing the script after the element has been added to the DOM?

Comment: `</script>` tag should be closed and you probably put the js before the div

Comment: Have a look at the console and tell us if you get any error and which ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All else being equal, you're likely executing your script before the page's content has had a chance to load.

**Change:**

```
<script>
document.getElementById("textbox_jbeeb_8").innerHTML = "Updated text";
<script>
```

**To:**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    document.getElementById("textbox_jbeeb_8").innerHTML = "Updated text";
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Close your script tag**

nothing is changed because your browser isn't interpreting that as javascript, with two script tags being open.

**[With closed script tag](http://jsfiddle.net/xDy5J/3/)**
**[Without script tag closed](http://jsfiddle.net/xDy5J/2/)**

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("textbox_jbeeb_8").innerHTML = "Updated text";
</script>
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? if you follow the jsfiddle links, i clear prove that the problem is caused by the script not being closed.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote <script> instead of </script> while asking here.

Comment: Looks like the downvote was because someone assumed it was a typo in the question. Which it was.